# Procedure or function in stored procedure has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am experiencing the problem on subject with the following code and cannot figure out what's wrong with it:

**Stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddRateTypeRoomTypeCombination]
(
     @RatePlanName NVARCHAR(50),
     @OpenFrom DATE,
     @OpenTo DATE,
     @Active BIT,
     @RoomTypeId INT)
AS
    DECLARE @Result INT

   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM dbo.RateType WITH (UPDLOCK)
              WHERE RatePlanName = @RatePlanName) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @Result = -1
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.RateType (RatePlanName, OpenFrom, OpenTo, Active)
       VALUES (@RatePlanName, @OpenFrom, @OpenTo, @Active)

        /******  return the last identity value inserted into an identity column ******/
       DECLARE @RateTypeid INT
       SET @RateTypeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       INSERT INTO dbo.RateRoomCombination(RateTypeId, RoomTypeId)
       VALUES (@RateTypeId, @RoomTypeId)

       SELECT @Result = @@ERROR
   END

   IF @Result <> 0
   BEGIN
       ROLLBACK
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       COMMIT
   END
   RETURN @Result
GO
```

This is the function that I wrote in order to insert data into my 2 tables `RateType` and `RateRoomCombination`:

```
Function AddRateType(RatePlanName As String) As Integer
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "spAddRateTypeRoomTypeCombination"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RatePlanName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxRateName.Text.Trim()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CheckBox3.Checked
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpenFrom", Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox1.Text.Trim()))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpenTo", Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox2.Text.Trim()))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Int))
        cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        For Each item As ListItem In chkRoomTypes.Items
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RateTypeId", SqlDbType.Int))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RoomTypeId", SqlDbType.Int))
        Next
        Dim commandResult As Integer = 1
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            commandResult = CType(cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value, Integer)
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            commandResult = ex.Number
            ' Use the following 3 lines to understand better the error
            Dim msg As String = "Insert Error:"
            msg += ex.Message
            Throw New Exception(msg)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
        Return commandResult
    End Using
End Function
```

Error I get:

> System.Exception: 'Insert Error:Procedure or function spAddRateTypeRoomTypeCombination has too many arguments specified.'

If I execute my stored procedure from SQL with 1 RateTypeId and 1 RoomTypeId, my DB gets updated. If I add more than 1 RoomTypeId (being the case I am trying to perform on my page), SQL throws the same error as per above: too many arguments.

I really cannot figure out what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What command are you running when you execute it directly? Passing too many arguments to a stored procedure should always throw that same error message.

Comment: I execute DB]
GO  
EXEC dbo.spAddRateTypeAndRoomtareCombination_UsingExists @RatePlanName = 'Standard', @OpenFrom='2019-03-10T00:00:00', @OpenTo='2019-04-10T00:00:00', @Active=True, @RoomTypeId='5'

Comment: Your post says you use "1 RateTypeId and 1 RoomTypeId" when you executed from SQL. There's no RateTypeID specified in that command. In your function you're trying to use more parameters than are specified in the stored procedure. You've got 5 parameters specified in your stored procedure definition and that's all it can take. You can't arbitrarily add parameters to the call - it doesn't work like that. You would need do something like build a list and then split it inside the stored procedure or create something like a user-defined table type and pass in your values with that.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons for your error, and they're both right here:

```
    For Each item As ListItem In chkRoomTypes.Items
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RateTypeId", SqlDbType.Int))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RoomTypeId", SqlDbType.Int))
    Next
```

1. Your stored procedure doesn't even have a `@RateTypeId` parameter (it has a local variable by that name).  So you can't pass a parameter to it in your .net command.
2. The `@RoomTypeId` parameter in your stored procedure is of type INT.   That means you can only pass ONE int value to it.  You can't add multiple `@RoomTypeId` parameters to the .net command and pass it to this stored procedure.   If you want to do that, you should look into making it a Table-Valued Parameter.

Comment: You mean that every single time I need to insert more tham 1 row in a many to many/joint table like I m trying to do I always need to create a table valued parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can't add more than one parameter with the same name to a SQL Command, so if you have more than one `RateTypeId` to pass, then you need to pass them all in a single parameter.   You COULD use a delimited string instead of a TVP, but a TVP is easier to deal with in the Stored Procedure code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very last question: can I still use the DECLARE RateTypeid INT
       SET RateTypeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() in order to add also the RateTypeId? In brief, i need the TVP to take the Ids of several roomtypes and take the last RateTypeId to which the rooms are associated.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, in which case you simply would not pass a `@RateTypeID` parameter from the .net app at all.   It would be strictly a local variable in the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi @Tab Alleman, I am definetely going on TVP as you suggested. I am now creating my DataTable to be assigned to the Paremeter Name of my application code.  Private Function GetRoomTypeIds() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(1) {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("RoomTypeId", GetType(Integer))})
        For Each li As ListItem In chkRoomTypes.Items
            dt.Rows.Add(txtId1.Text, chkRoomTypes.SelectedValue)
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function